# Galaxy S3 with 4.1.1 ActivSync contacts not showing

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, active-sync

I have connected my S3 to my company's 2007 Exchange server through the native Microsoft ActivSync account settings.

I get mail, calendar and contacts - then at some point, the contacts all disappear.  They still exist in Outlook/Exchange, but will not show on my S3.

This seems to be an issue related to my contacts list: Other users using S3's on the same exchange server aren't seeing the same issue.

Are there any characters that shouldn't be in my contacts that might be causing some corruption or something?

Thanks.